# How to import my local python modules from my local notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, python-import, python-packaging

My project structure:

```
parent_folder/
|-- Project/
|   |-- README.md
|   |-- setup.py
|   |-- package/
|   |   |-- __init__.py
|   |   |-- utils/
|   |   |   |-- __init__.py
|   |   |   |-- module1.py
|   |   |   |-- module2.py
|   |   |-- models/
|   |   |   |-- __init__.py
|   |   |   |-- model.py
|   |-- notebooks/
|       |-- notebook.ipynb
```

I would like to import `module1`, `module2` and `model` from notebook but Python said: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'package'`.

I tried to create `__init__.py` in `utils` and `models` and `setup.py` in project folder.

Comment: Easiest would probably be to add the Project folder to your `PYTHONPATH` environment variable, then you can say `from package.utils import module1` and from `package.models.model import MyModel`.

Comment: _I tried to create `__init__.py` in utils and models and `setup.py` in project folder_ Then why aren't those shown in your project structure?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: how do you import it? Show it in question (not in comments) because we can't see your code, and we can't read in your mind. You have to show all details in question.

Comment: I added my project to PYTHONPATH but it doesn't work.

Comment: Do not play with `PYTHONPATH` or `sys.path`. It almost never is a good idea. There almost always is a better, cleaner solution. -- What is missing in your question is the description of how you try to import. -- You should import like this: `from package.utils import module1`, there are other ways but this is most likely the one you want.

Comment: OK I delete PYTHONPATH and I use `from package.utils import module1` and it works but `dir(package)` doesn't return `utils` and `models` in the list. I try just `package.utils` and I have `AttributeError: module 'package' has no attribute 'utils'`. What can I write in each `__init__.py` files ?

Comment: All importations work but `package.utils` doesn't